# Manage identical requests with RxJava

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

Assume that I have a fetcher that fetches an image from a given link on a separate thread. The image will then be cached in memory. Once the image already gets cached, the fetcher won't re-fetch the link. The fetcher is considered as an Observable. There may be many subscribers that ask the fetcher for the image. After the first-ever subscriber subscribe the fetcher, the fetcher will shoot network. However, if there's a 2nd subscriber comes to subscribe then, the fetcher shouldn't shoot yet another request while it's already been fetching one before. After that, if the fetch finishes, both subscribers will get the image. Right now, if there's a 3rd subscriber that comes, the fetcher will emit the image right away.

How can I implement the scenario above with RxJava approach? What I expect is to utilise some sort of existing operators, compose them in ways much more declarative, and most importantly, to avoid the overhead of synchronised, lock, and atomic stuff.

Comment: This scenario sounds like image loading library. After a fetcher downloads an image, this image will be cached in memory as key-value pairs with url as key. So other fetchers that want to get the same image will check the map with given url. With a condition check (like null or incomplete) then it will or will not start a new http request. As to emit, unless you want to persist the image then it's UI operation which is on demand. If there is no demand from ImageView wanting the image then no loading.

Comment: Also, I would just use an image loading library like Picasso and let it handle the caching (I think memory-only caching of image won't get you very far anyway with the limited memory of Android devices). If you want you can wrap Picasso in an `Observable` though by using Picasso's `Target`s.

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in the question: "Assume that I have a fetcher that fetches an image from a given link on a separate thread. The image will then be **cached** in memory."

And the answer is the `cache()` operator:

"remember the sequence of items emitted by the Observable and emit the same sequence to future Subscribers"

from: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Observable-Utility-Operators

So, the following `Observable` should only fetch the image once, no matter how `Subscribers` subscribe to it:

```
Observable<Bitmap> cachedBitmap = fetchBitmapFrom(url).cache();
```

**EDIT:**

I think the following example proves that the upstream `Observable` is subscribed only once, even if multiple Subscriptions come in before the `Observable` has emitted anything. This should also be true for network requests.

```
package com.example;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class SimpleCacheTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Observable<Integer> cachedSomething = getSomething().cache();

        System.out.println("before first subscription");
        cachedSomething.subscribe(new SimpleLoggingSubscriber<Integer>("1"));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("before second subscription");
        cachedSomething.subscribe(new SimpleLoggingSubscriber<Integer>("2"));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("quit");
    }

    private static class SimpleLoggingSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {

        private final String tag;

        public SimpleLoggingSubscriber(final String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("onCompleted (" + tag + ")");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("onError (" + tag + ")");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            System.out.println("onNext (" + tag + "): " + t);
        }
    }

    private static Observable<Integer> getSomething() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>(){

            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                System.out.println("going to sleep now...");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                subscriber.onNext(1);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
before first subscription
going to sleep now...
before second subscription
onNext (1): 1
onNext (2): 1
onCompleted (1)
onCompleted (2)
quit
```

Comment: This won't filter out requests in progress - if your second request for an image comes in before the first one has returned. In fact, it won't stop the request being run multiple times at all - this solution assumes that the url->cache mapping is done elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that is true - please have a look at the example code I added. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Okay, I guess we're looking at the problem differently. This works if you already have an Observable that you know supplies the image for the URL (on subscription). If, however, you just know that you need to get an image for a URL (and you want to abstract the fetching and caching of that image), Rx is probably not a good solution for that - especially on Android.

Comment: Re-reading the question again, it's tough to say - this will work if you build the observable for the image and then keep a reference to that (as in your example), _knowing you'll always have the same URL_. If the URL changes, then your Observable changes, and this falls apart - you have to cache references to Observables for different URLs, each of which are caching images themselves... Eek.

Comment: @Adam S: Yes, you are right - using `cache()` would indeed make it necessary to keep all the (cached) Observables in a `Map<Url, Observable<Bitmap>>` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished via ConcurrentMap and AsyncSubject:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import rx.*;
import rx.Scheduler.Worker;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.AsyncSubject;


public class ObservableImageCache {
    final ConcurrentMap<String, AsyncSubject<BufferedImage>> image = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public Observable<BufferedImage> get(String url) {
        AsyncSubject<BufferedImage> result = image.get(url);
        if (result == null) {
            result = AsyncSubject.create();
            AsyncSubject<BufferedImage> existing = image.putIfAbsent(url, result);
            if (existing == null) {
                System.out.println("Debug: Downloading " + url);
                AsyncSubject<BufferedImage> a = result;
                Worker w = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
                w.schedule(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500); // for demo
                        URL u = new URL(url);

                        try (InputStream openStream = u.openStream()) {
                            a.onNext(ImageIO.read(openStream));
                        }
                        a.onCompleted();
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                        a.onError(ex);
                    } finally {
                        w.unsubscribe();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                result = existing;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObservableImageCache cache = new ObservableImageCache();
        CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(4);

        Observable<BufferedImage> img1 = cache.get("https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/create.png");
        System.out.println("Subscribing for IMG1");
        img1.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("IMG1: " + e.getWidth() + "x" + e.getHeight()), Throwable::printStackTrace, cdl::countDown);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        Observable<BufferedImage> img2 = cache.get("https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/create.png");
        System.out.println("Subscribing for IMG2");
        img2.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("IMG2: " + e.getWidth() + "x" + e.getHeight()), Throwable::printStackTrace, cdl::countDown);

        Observable<BufferedImage> img3 = cache.get("https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/amb.png");
        Observable<BufferedImage> img4 = cache.get("https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/amb.png");

        Thread.sleep(500);

        System.out.println("Subscribing for IMG3");
        img3.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("IMG3: " + e.getWidth() + "x" + e.getHeight()), Throwable::printStackTrace, cdl::countDown);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("-> Should be immediate: ");
        System.out.println("Subscribing for IMG4");
        img4.subscribe(e -> System.out.println("IMG4: " + e.getWidth() + "x" + e.getHeight()), Throwable::printStackTrace, cdl::countDown);

        cdl.await();
    }
}
```

I'm using the ConcurrentMap's putIfAbsent to make sure only one download is triggered for a new url; everyone else will receive the same AsyncSubject on which they can 'wait' and get the data once available and immediately after that. Usually, you'd want to limit the number of concurrent downloads by using a custom Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for this, I never quite understood the use case for AsyncSubject; the doc is not as clear as it could be.  In particular, I didn't realize you could subscribe to the AsyncSubject after its source Observable had completed and still get the source Observable's last emission.  The marble diagram and sample code at http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/AsyncSubject.html don't show this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ConnectableObservable` and the `.replay()` method.

I'm currently using this is my fragments to handle orientation changes:

Fragment's onCreate:

```
ConnectableObservable<MyThing> connectableObservable = 
    retrofitService.fetchMyThing()
        .map(...)
        .replay();

connectableObservable.connect(); // this starts the actual network call
```

Fragment's onCreateView:

```
Subscription subscription = connectableObservable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(mything -> dosomething());
```

What happens is that I make 1 network request only, and any subscriber will (eventually/immediately) get that response.