# emit items only if the last value of another observable meets a condition

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, frp

I need to implement an observable that would ask to load data only if it's not already being loaded. I was thinking of having two observables: one for load requests and another for loading state. I'm not sure if the following scenario is possible and need your guidance:

> load request observable:     -- request -- skip whatever items unless state is False -- another request
>
> Is loading state observable: -- True -------------------------------------------------------------False---

Thanks.

P.S. I wish the solution wouldn't contain side effects.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682895/manage-identical-requests-with-rxjava/29746800#29746800) I gave an example for an image-caching solution which made sure images to a specific URL are loaded once.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's possible to avoid side effects in my scenario?

Comment: What kind of side-effects do you want to avoid?